# how to draw a cube

Tags: opengl

I have 8 vertices. I want to draw cube with this vertices. How can I draw cube with vertices?

vertices:

```
   v1, v2, v3,v4, v5,v6,v7,v8

   they are array of float with 3 elements(float v1[3])
```

I have done

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(v1[0], v1  [1], v1[2]);
        // do same thing for other 7 vertex
glEnd();
```

Comment: Yesss, and? Have you heard about VBOs?

Comment: Have you considered a cursory Google search? http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cube-in-OpenGL

Comment: @Mikhail how can draw it with triangles

Answer (score 0):

To summarize from http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cube-in-OpenGL

> Now we add the vertices between the glBegin() and glEnd() lines.

```
// Multi-colored side - FRONT
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5);       // P1
glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5);       // P2
glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5);       // P3
glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5);       // P4
glEnd();
```

Comment: hoe can I draw it with triangle

Comment: What? You asked for a cube, we gave it to you. Why are you asking for triangles now? The question needs to be closed.